# Log 404'd URL's with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How would I got about logging the URL when a user get's a 404 page? In my logs I see a lot of NotFoundExceptions being thrown, but that's not exactly useful information.

Ideally I'd like to log the URL's to the database so I can produce easy-to-read reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put PHP code in your 404 page to log it to a database, with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: I was actually just thinking this. I think that would be the simplest solution. Thanks.